# How to connect to remote phpMyAdmin server using NodeJS + ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, phpmyadmin

I'm setting up a GraphQL server however I need to connect to a remote phpMyAdmin server which my friend provided and i am getting the error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 54.193.13.37/phpmyadmin 54.193.13.37/phpmyadmin:3306
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
```

here is the code i use to connect

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "54.193.13.37/phpmyadmin",
    user: "some_user",
    password: "some_password",
    database:"some_DB",
})

db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

I've tried removing "http://", adding port, also the IP address 54.193.13.37 is an IP address for his clan website. So, the only way i have access to the database is by 54.193.13.37/phpmyadmin and i dont have any access to any config files or whatsoever, it's just a remote database that he gave me.

Thanks to whoever can help!

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool. it's not a database. It's used to interact with MySQL, the actual database.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the phpmyadmin in the host. Try host: `host: "54.193.13.37"`.
Phpmyadmin is a web interface, but you want to connect directly to the mysql server wich is normaly on Port 3306.

Comment: well yeah i did that but it connects to a website and gives me an error:` connect ETIMEDOUT`

Comment: Please check the configuration of the phpmyadmin. Maybe the mysql server runs on a different IP-Adress than the phpmyadmin or not  on the default Port. There is no Port 3306 open to the outside so please look up the right details.